# Calculating Euclidean Distance With Given Lists

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

```
def distance(alist, blist):
    sum_of = 0
    for x in alist:
        for y in blist:
            ans = (x - y)**2
            sum_of += ans
    return (sum_of)**(1/2)
print(distance([1, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3])) #1.4142135623730951
print(distance([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3])) #1.0
print(distance([2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3])) #0.0
print(distance([1, 1], [2, 2])) #1.4142135623730951
```

So I have a set of test cases which give me two lists with numbers. My task is to calculate the euclidean distance with the given lists. However, I am not getting the right results. I am instead getting 3.7416573867739413, 3.0, 2.0 and 2.0. This is what I have so far, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
   for x in alist:
      for y in blist:
```

So for each point in `alist`, you are visiting all points in `blist`. For example, for `alist = [1, 2, 3]` and `blist = [4, 5, 6]`, this loop would generate pairs `(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)` But what you want to do is to look at only `(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)`. This can be achieved with the zip function. If you iterate over `zip(alist, blist)`, it will iterate over those points. You can confirm this by executing

```
list(zip(alist, blist))
Out: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

So if you change the nested loops with a single loop over zip, it will calculate the correct distance.

```
def distance(alist, blist):
    sum_of = 0
    for x, y in zip(alist, blist):
        ans = (x - y)**2
        sum_of += ans
    return (sum_of)**(1/2)


distance([1, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3])
Out: 1.4142135623730951
```

Comment: Oh okay, I see. If you don't mind explaining, what exactly does "zip" do?

Comment: zip(...)
    zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

    Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
    from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
    in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.

Comment: @EliezerShahid you can always find out what a builtin or standard library function does by reading the documentation: [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).